# How to create a service networking creation from a gcp project to "default" network

Tags: sql, networking, command-line-interface, gcloud

I wanted to use the gcloud cli to create an sql instance that is accessible on the default network. So I tried this:

```
gcloud beta sql instances create instance1 \
  --network projects/peak-freedom-xxxxx/global/networks/default
```

And I get the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) [INTERNAL_ERROR] Failed to create subnetwork.
Please create Service Networking connection with service 'servicenetworking.googleapis.com'
from consumer project '56xxxxxxxxx' network 'default' again.
```

When you go to the console to create it, you can check Private IP you can see this:

[image]

And there's an "Allocate and connect" button. So I'm guessing that's what I need to do. But I can't figure out how to do that with the gcloud cli.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT 1**:

I've tried setting the `--network` to `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/testing-project-xxx/global/networks/default`

Which resulted in

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) [INTERNAL_ERROR] Failed to 
create subnetwork. Set Service Networking service account as 
servicenetworking.serviceAgent role on consumer project
```

Then I tried recreating a completely new project and enabling the Service Networking API like so:

```
gcloud --project testing-project-xxx \
  services enable \
  servicenetworking.googleapis.com
```

And then creating the DB resulted in the same error. So I tried to manually add the `servicenetworking.serviceAgent` role and ran:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding testing-project-xxx \
  --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECTNUMBER@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role=roles/servicenetworking.serviceAgent
```

This succeeded with

```
Updated IAM policy for project [testing-project-xxx].
bindings:
- members:
  - user:email@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-OJECTNUMBERRP@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/servicenetworking.serviceAgent
etag: XxXxXX37XX0=
version: 1
```

But creating the DB failed with the same error. For reference, this is the command line I'm using to create the DB:

```
gcloud --project testing-project-xxx \
  beta sql instances create instanceName \
  --network=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/testing-project-xxx/global/networks/default \
  --database-version POSTGRES_11 \
  --zone europe-north1-a \
  --tier db-g1-small
```

Answer (score 0):

the network name of form "projects/peak-freedom-xxxxx/global/networks/default" is for creating SQL instances under shared VPC network. if you want to create an instance in a normal VPC network you should use:

```
gcloud --project=[PROJECT_ID] beta sql instances create [INSTANCE_ID]
       --network=[VPC_NETWORK_NAME]
       --no-assign-ip
```

where `[VPC_NETWORK_NAME]` is of the form  `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/networks/[VPC_NETWORK_NAME]`

for more information check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#new-private-instance).

Note: you need to configure private service access for this and it's one time action only. [follow instructions here to do so](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! I tried this as well (Witout the `--no-assign-ip` because I want to be able to proxy to it publicly using the `cloud_sql_proxy`), but then I get a `Failed to create subnetwork. Set Service Networking service account as servicenetworking.serviceAgent role on consumer project` ... trying to figure out how to do that now. Any tips there?

Comment: try disabling and re-enabling the Service Networking API and then the permissions will be reset to all users automatically. If the above solution does not resolve the issue, you can grant the role permissions ‘servicenetworking.serviceAgent’ to your Service Networking service account manually to fix this issue by running the following gcloud command in the Cloud Shell `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOURPROJECT --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECTNUMBER@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/servicenetworking.serviceAgent
`

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my post above to detail everything I've done. Manually adding the thing didn't work either :(

Comment: hey @aliak, try to run the same command again mentioned in your **edit1** with a `--verbosity=debug` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) and edit your post with the error logs that you receive. Another option I suggest is to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) as they have more visibilty on the subject and why you are receiving this error.

Comment: hey @Methkal thanks a lot for the help! The `debug` didn't really say much else. It added a python stack trace but that's it. I'll see if I can go for a support case. I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access) which is I think what I'll have to do but it seems quite involved. So I may just give up on this one.

Comment: hey @aliak , indeed, if you have never If you have not previously done so, follow the instructions [here to configure private services access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access). it's one time only action and you don't need to do it again. I will update my answer with this.